# VBA: Sum variable with for loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sumifs

I am attempting to sum cells that hold specific text strings in the row. Below is what I've come up with, however, I keep receiving an error on the second loop when it reaches the first currency text.

> Run-Time error '6': Overflow

```
    'Add Futures Data
        Morgan_Stanley_File.Activate
        Dim Currency_JPY As Integer: Currency_JPY = 0
        Dim Currency_USD As Integer: Currency_USD = 0
        Dim Currency_EUR As Integer: Currency_EUR = 0
        Dim Currency_GBP As Integer: Currency_GBP = 0
        Dim Currency_AUD As Integer: Currency_AUD = 0

        For Each MCell In Range("H1:H" & bottomL)
            If MCell.Value = "N" And MCell.Offset(0, -3) = "JPY" Then
                Currency_JPY = Currency_JPY + MCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
            ElseIf MCell.Value = "N" And MCell.Offset(0, -3) = "USD" Then
                Currency_USD = Currency_USD + MCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
            ElseIf MCell.Value = "N" And MCell.Offset(0, -3) = "EUR" Then
                Currency_EUR = Currency_EUR + MCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
            ElseIf MCell.Value = "N" And MCell.Offset(0, -3) = "GBP" Then
                Currency_GBP = Currency_GBP + MCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
            ElseIf MCell.Value = "N" And MCell.Offset(0, -3) = "AUD" Then
                Currency_AUD = Currency_AUD + MCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
            End If
        Next MCell

        wb.Activate
        Initial_Margin.Select
        Range("A" & LastDate).Offset(1, 5).Value = Currency_JPY
        Range("A" & LastDate).Offset(1, 6).Value = Currency_USD
        Range("A" & LastDate).Offset(1, 7).Value = Currency_EUR
        Range("A" & LastDate).Offset(1, 8).Value = Currency_GBP
        Range("A" & LastDate).Offset(1, 9).Value = Currency_AUD
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Could be the data type as you are declaring the sums as int's and if the values are too large it could throw an error. Maybe declare as long or single.

Comment: What error do you get? Is this the line that's highlighted; "Range("A" & LastDate).Offset(1, 5).Value = Currency_JPY"?

Comment: I receive a Run-Time error '6': Overflow error. The data type shouldn't be too large as they are just values in the general format.

Would there be a problem with the syntax of the below (the highlighted error when debugging)? I wonder if it keeps looping internally leading to the runtime error.

Currency_AUD = Currency_AUD + MCell.Offset(0, 19).Value

Comment: Test your VBA script with values that add up to less than 32,767, and values that add up to more to confirm that it's not too large.

Comment: It worked!! Much thanks! I hope no idea about the 'integer' cap. 
You guys rock.

Comment: Glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

Consider Excel's formula function, [SUMIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) that allows multiple criteria, similar to [AVERAGEIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690). And for other aggregates like median, max, min, there is the [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) within cells. No VBA `for` looping or `if` logic needed.

```
A       B       C
N     150     USD
N     250     JPY
N     175     EUR
Y     185     JPY
N     225     USD
N     225     AUD
N     225     GPD
...

[JPY TOTAL CELL] = SUMIFS($B$1:$B$100, $C$1:$C$100, "JPY", $A$1:$A$100, "N")
[USD TOTAL CELL] = SUMIFS($B$1:$B$100, $C$1:$C$100, "USD", $A$1:$A$100, "N")
[EUR TOTAL CELL] = SUMIFS($B$1:$B$100, $C$1:$C$100, "EUR", $A$1:$A$100, "N")
[GBP TOTAL CELL] = SUMIFS($B$1:$B$100, $C$1:$C$100, "GBP", $A$1:$A$100, "N")
[AUD TOTAL CELL] = SUMIFS($B$1:$B$100, $C$1:$C$100, "AUD", $A$1:$A$100, "N")
```